# Recreate an activity in another activity?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-lifecycle

So I have two activites where I can switch between. Let's call them ActivityA and ActivityB. 
Now if I'm in ActivityB and it somehow crashes and I start my App again it should appear the ActivityB and not A.

I thought of SharedPreferences(I already used it for the switching) and savedInstanceState, but can the last one handle with the savedInstanceState of other activites or just by its own?
Can I somehow tell ActivityA to look if there is already an instance of ActivityB and if so ro start it immediately?

Comment: Why are you trying to "patch the pipe" instead of replacing it? In English: why don't you fix the crash instead of struggling to find hacks for crashed scenarios?

Comment: "and it somehow crashes" Wouldn't it be better to fix the crash instead of hacking on system?

Comment: I just want my App to be prepared of "every scenario".

Comment: Also wouldn't it be the same scenario if I started my App go in an activity and then start it again and it isn't in the activity I have been?

Answer (score 0):

When an app starts, Android always runs whichever activity it is told to (as defined in the manifest) - which can work to your advantage. You should be able to create a splash activity that determines what the last activity was (via tracking, sharedPrefs or perhaps savedInstanceState - I haven't mucked with the latter much), and then launch the appropriate activity before `finish();`-ing the splash activity.

Make sure the splash looks decent though - add in a handler that will keep it up for at least 1500-2000ms.